# guarantee order of table valued function results

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, user-defined-functions

***PREMISE**: The application code cannot be changed. The conditions are very specific. I am looking for something off the books, a last resort workaround if you may.*

I have a table-valued function (inline) that produces between 2 and 7 records.  At times it could be only 1 or up to 15 (but rarely).

The function is only used by an application in this way, without any ORDER BY.

```
select * from dbo.myfunction(...)
```

Is there any way at all, in your experience, to <s>guarantee</s> ensure (as far as you have ever observed using a particular technique) that the results are returned ordered by the second column?  Columns are:  varchar(3), datetime, varchar(50).
Don't get me started on **select ***, it is *INTENTIONAL* so that the front end will display however many columns I make the function display in the future.

<s>From experience, with a single index (clustered PK) to traverse the data, any current version of SQL Server and SP level should always perform a simple INDEX SCAN on <20 records without parallelism, thereby giving me ordered results in the application select.</s>

Your thoughts?  I would prefer to keep theory out of the discussion. If you can stick to practical experience and keep sermons about best practice at home, I would also appreciate it.

---

**UPDATED**
This is what it looks like now

```
create function dbo.myfunction(....)
returns @RES table
    (
    [#] int identity primary key clustered,
    [Varchar3Col] varchar(3),
    [DateTimeCol] datetime,
    [Varchar50Col] varchar(50)
    ) as
BEGIN
declare @RES2 table
    (
    rn int,
    [Varchar3Col] varchar(3),
    [DateTimeCol] datetime,
    [Varchar50Col] varchar(50)
    )

insert @RES2
select rn=row_number() over (order by action_time),
    [Varchar3Col]
    [DateTimeCol]
    [Varchar50Col]
from (.....)
inner join (.....) ON (.....)

declare @i int
set @i = 0
while @@rowcount > 0 begin
    set @i=@i+1
    insert @RES
    select [Varchar3Col], [DateTimeCol], [Varchar50Col]
    from @RES2
    where rn=@i
end
return
END
GO
```

- If you look at the above, the population of @RES is done sequentially in the order desired, manually.
- @RES has a clustered PK representing the order inserted.
- the columns are small enough that 20 rows should always fit in a single 8K page

Would this work (with the straightforward SELECT from the application layer)?

Comment: No, there is no guarantee. If you want a guarantee, add an `ORDER BY` to the application. That's how the guarantee is enforced. This isn't a sermon about best practice, it's just the truth... the query optimizer *can* choose to order your results in whatever way *it* deems most efficient. And yes that can happen with 20 rows, and it can change with a statistics change on the base table(s), a cumulative update, service pack, upgrade, etc.

Comment: "can choose".. "deems".. "can happen". Right, so SQL Server is a computer program with fixed algorithms right, not a washing machine with fuzzy logic. So what does it *really* do?

Comment: I didn't write the optimizer, so I can't really tell you what it actually does. But I can tell you that it is an extremely complicated piece of code written by some of the brightest minds on the planet. I doubt they will tell you how it works, because it's kind of the reason SQL Server does so well, but I will bet you a box of donuts that they will tell you the same thing I'm telling you. **DO NOT RELY ON OBSERVED ORDER BEHAVIOR TO REMAIN CONSTANT**. If you want a guarantee, add an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I suppose then that no programmer has ever used undocumented features in the Win32 API, given that MS gives no guarantees? I'm not after a gold plated guarantee, just some black box observation backed by experience or inside knowledge for a *very* specific problem domain. You clearly don't have what I am after because you haven't played off the book, so (no disrespect but) I don't think you are my intended audience.

Comment: People use undocumented stuff all the time, but usually they understand the risks, and don't infer any guarantee about their behavior (unless they don't know any better, or don't care). I'm just not understanding what's so hard about adding ORDER BY 2 to your application code. Were it my app, I'd sleep better at night with an explicit guarantee... and you could have been done with that in the time you spent crafting this question and belittling anyone who questions you. Have fun with your problem.

Comment: @Aaron. Let's say Joe has a cancer. Doctors (the experts) pronounce terminal in 1 month and no recourse. Should Joe seek alternative medicine/prayer/voodoo? Okay I failed to mention the APP cannot be changed. But here's where I am, I have a problem and am looking for a way to work around it, undocumented, unguaranteed or what not. This is not an all encompassing question, just one very specific case and conditions. Appreciate your time on this question but if you feel you need throw MSSQL bibles at me, I have an inkling I can hold my own against you any other day.

Comment: Okay, well if you want to rely on behavior that you understand is not guaranteed, why are you bothering asking the question? You seem to have known in advance what the response would be. You need to decide whether the consequences are worth it... what exactly will happen when this app, which made assumptions about order without explicitly stating it, suddenly starts receiving results in an unexpected order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For an inline TVF nothing will really work. Not only that, the inline TVF may even return *more* rows than you believe it should, and the rows will be trimmed *after* the TVF executed (basically a predicate in the TVF definition can be pulled out of the TVF and moved somewhere else in the query tree). See [T-SQL functions do no imply a certain order of execution](http://rusanu.com/2011/08/10/t-sql-functions-do-no-imply-a-certain-order-of-execution/) for an example of this happening.

Converting the inline TVF to a multi statement one will introduce some procedural order, since the statements cannot be executed out of order, but the TVF result may be re-ordered, sorted, split, spooled, basically mangled by the optimizer generated plan and in the end break your assumption about output order. I'm afraid if you *must* have a certain order of execution, cursors are your best friend.

Comment: I have added the body of the function. I have converted it to multi-statement and am using a loop to guarantee insertion order (along clustered PK). Does that help?

Comment: Can you conceive of a reason why the QO would reorder, (re)sort or split a TVF result that has fewer than 20 records?

Answer (score 2):

Is it just that you don't like the answer you are hearing?  Truth is, order is only guaranteed with an order by clause.  It's not an opinion, it is fact. There is no alternative if it is a guarantee you are looking for.

Comment: I have edited the question to better reflect the reason for the question. SQLkiwi read it right.

Answer (score -1):

If only a single app is using the function, in this particular way as you mentioned ( so not joined/applied to another object) this should have been a sproc ! 
Add an oder by clause to the data returning query to receive the result set in a particular order.

There is always a risk your fn will be used by another dev, but not in the way you intended it to be used, causing issues of all kind. Performance being the one I would be worried about.

Answer (score -3):

You'll have a better shot at a predictable query plan if you use a single-statement TVF instead of a multistatement TVF.  ROW_NUMBER OVER should enfore the ordering you want in your RES2 query, and if it doesn't, just put it inside a CTE and order by your row number column.  See below.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFunction]
(
/*
Parameters
*/
)
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN
WITH res2
(
    rn,
    Varchar3Col,
    DateTimeCol,
    Varchar50Col
)
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY action_time) AS rn,
        Varchar3Col,
        action_time AS DateTimeCol,
        Varchar50Col
    FROM
/*
        [...from statement...]
*/      
)
SELECT
    rn,
    Varchar3Col,
    DateTimeCol,
    Varchar50Col
FROM
    res2
ORDER BY
    rn;
```

Comment: Why do you think this is any more guaranteed to persist a certain order when called without an order by, than the multi-statement tvf? Sorting can still impact the result AFTER the function results have been materialized, which is why there is no guarantee no matter what is inside the function.

Comment: The order by clause at the end of the CTE will guarantee the order the rows are returned from the function.  It runs as an atomic statement as opposed to the iterative inserts in the multi-statement TVF proposed in the question.  This will run more efficiently.

Comment: It is not guaranteed if you just say SELECT * FROM dbo.MyFunction() without ORDER BY. Not sure how else to explain this. Note that running this 1000 times and observing the same order each time is **not** the same as a guarantee.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() applies a row number ranking based on the sort order passed in (action_time).  The inner statement aliases that column as rn.  The outer statement orders by rn.  How is the order not guaranteed?

Comment: Because the optimizer can re-sort the OUTER results **after** the function has produced its output. You need an ORDER BY outside the function if you want the order to be guaranteed. Without it, you may enjoy the order you want by coincidence, but it is not guaranteed. This is similar to how TOP 100 PERCENT ... ORDER BY in a view no longer guarantees ordering if you select from the view without order by, and how GROUP BY alone no longer dictates ordering by the same columns as the GROUP BY. We're not making this stuff up - your function simply does not guarantee order.

Comment: So it will ignore the outer order by clause?  I have never seen this behavior.  If that's true that strikes me as a pretty big bug.

Comment: If you believe ROW_NUMBER guarantees order of output, read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110643/can-i-depend-on-order-of-output-when-using-row-number/1110735#1110735

Comment: How is this a bug? The ORDER BY inside the function tells the function how to order the rows; row_number says how to apply the row number value, but not necessarily how the orders will return; top...order by similarly dictates how the rows are chosen but again does not guarantee they will be returned in the same order. There is another layer: when you SELECT from the function, **that** is the outer query I'm talking about, and is precisely where the ORDER BY needs to go if you want a guarantee. **Sort last, or don't rely on it.**